# Why does npm install keep saving under node modules folder even though i changed directory to another folder?

Tags: node.js, npm, mean-stack

In terminal, I entered the command `cd /Users/MyUserName/Google/Google Drive/Coding` then entered the command `npm install underscore`. So I figured the underscore module would be saved under my `Coding` folder; however, it keeps saving under the directory: `/Users/MyUserName/node_modules/`

How do I change the setting so that when ever I change my directory in terminal and enter a `npm install` command, the module gets installed in the respective changed directory?

Comment: I believe npm only install in a folder if it contains a `package.json` file.

Comment: I'm following the Lynda NodeJS tutorial and the instructor doesn't have a `package.json` file in his empty folder

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#more-information):

> Starting at the `$PWD`, npm will walk up the folder tree checking for a folder that contains either a package.json file, or a node_modules folder. If such a thing is found, then that is treated as the effective "current directory" for the purpose of running npm commands. (This behavior is inspired by and similar to git's .git-folder seeking logic when running git commands in a working dir.)
>
> If no package root is found, then the current folder is used.

So it seems the package is installed under your home folder because it already contains a `node_modules` folder. If you remove that the install should go into the current folder.

Alternatively: Add a `node_modules` folder to the current folder.